# How to set cookie in Jersey?

Tags: jsp, cookies, jersey

I am using jersey jax-rs in myeclipse as backend of my project and jsp as frontend. I want to set cookie from server after successful login. In the jersey's official document, I can only find how to get cookie by jersey. Does anyone can give me a demo to do such things?

This is my login part and I return a response and redirect to URL "/" which means index.jsp.

```
@Path("/login")
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response login(@FormParam("email") String email,
        @FormParam("password") String password) {
    Map<String, Object> model = MapFactory.newHashMapInstance();
    model.put("email", email);
    model.put("password", password);
    loginCheck(model);
    if (model.get("emailCheck").equals("ok")
            && model.get("passwordCheck").equals("ok")) {
        return Response.ok(
                new Viewable("/index", new NewCookie("name",
                        "Hello, world!"))).build();
    } else {
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/login", model)).build();
    }
}
```

This is my "/" part:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public Response getIndex(@CookieParam("name") String name) {
    HashMap<String, Object> model = MapFactory.newHashMapInstance();
    model.put("name", name);
    System.out.println("cookie name:\t" + name);
    return Response.ok(new Viewable("/index", model)).build();
}
```

Every time I run this code, I find that I cannot get cookie from the index part. If you also ever bothered by this question and finally solved it, plz give me some directions, thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To set the cookie in your example, you can do something like this:

```
return Response.ok(new Viewable("/index", model))
               .cookie(new NewCookie("name", "Hello, world!"))
               .build();
```

But if you want to redirect to "/" you would also need to return 3xx response instead of 200, for example:

```
return Response.seeOther("/")
               .cookie(new NewCookie("name", "Hello, world!"))
               .build();
```

Comment: By the way, do you know how to clean them (in jersey) when I want to logout from my site?

Comment: Try setting the maxAge of the cookie to 0, using `Response.ok().cookie(new NewCookie("name", null, null, null, null, 0 /*maxAge*/, false)).build()`

Comment: Yeah, I am using maxAge to "clean" them. I just wonder whether there are some other ways like xxx.clean() method to clean the cookies. Anyway, this question has already been successfully solved. Thanks for your answering. Appreciate your sharing.