# get username and password in cookie value with web services

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I'm making an application with web services and i want to memorize username and password of user in cookie and then i want to resume the username and password of the user in another web service

```
NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie(new javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie("cookie", (username+password).hashCode()+""), "", 15*15, false);
```

in this line of code i create the cookie but I can't take the values ​​in another web service

I'm new to java programming, help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't store a user name or password let alone both into a cookie as a cookie can be easily read. Instead you should look at using a JWT or similar.

Checkout https://jwt.io

As for your question it looks like you're using Jersey in which this: [How to set cookie in Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231156/how-to-set-cookie-in-jersey) should answer your question. Note you set a cookie with a Response!

Comment: ok but i don't know how to implement it.. can you take me an example?

Comment: Implementing a JWT or the cookie? If its for the cookie, the link to a previous question shows you a code snippet at how to set a cookie on the client's browser by issuing it in a response.